# How to consolidate information from different sources in Google Sheets

Tags: worksheet-function, google-sheets

So I have a Google Sheet with several sheets (tabs) in it, like so:

```
Sheet 1 - Weapons                Legend
A       B       C       D        A = Date
5/3     John    Sword   10       B = From
6/3     Jack    Sword   10       C = For What
7/3     Jill    Mace    20       D = Amount

Sheet 2 - Supplies
A       B       C       D
5/3     Biff    Wood    20
7/3     Kent    Wood    20
8/3     Dann    Iron    40

Sheet 3 - Accessories
A       B       C       D
5/3     Luke    Ring    5
6/3     Gaia    Ring    5
8/3     Fonz    Belt    15
```

Now, the thing is, I want a Sheet 4 - Transactions.

- The numbers in Sheet 1 & Sheet 3 are 'Inflows' (sales made by shop), whereas the numbers in Sheet 2 are 'Outflows' (materials bought by shop).

I need something like this:

```
Sheet 4 - Transactions            (Opening Balance - 100)
A        B        C        D        E
5/3      John     Sword    10       110
5/3      Biff     Wood     (20)     90
5/3      Luke     Ring     5        95
6/3      Jack     Sword    10       105
6/3      Gaia     Ring     5        110
7/3      Jill     Mace     20       130
7/3      Kent     Wood     (20)     110
8/3      Dann     Iron     (40)     70
8/3      Fonz     Belt     15       85
```

To explain Sheet 4:

- **Col A** - Date
- **Col B** - Whom
- **Col C** - For What
- **Col D** - Amount
- **Col E** - Balance (computed)

I figure I need to put together some fancy query perhaps? A way to consolidate multiple queries?

I'd appreciate if you could provide your logic along with the code (if any), or even if there's a smarter way to do this. The end goal being to track the history of the money bag held by the shop.

Answer (score 1):

By using array formulas with embedded arrays you could append the three ranges in one. I.E.

```
=ArrayFormula(Sheet1!A1:D4;{Sheet2!A1:C3,Shee2!D1:D3*-1};Sheet3!A1:D4})
```

Then you could add the balance column next to the resulting range.